# Include all files in lib folder of NuGet package

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

My project references a NuGet package `SomePackage`, and when I build it, `SomePackage.dll` is copied to the bin folder. However, I actually want to be able to later run this `dll` (with a `dotnet` CLI command), and the NuGet package has the appropriate `JSON` file in its `lib` folder which I require:

```
SomePackage.dll
SomePackage.runtimeconfig.json
```

But when I build my project, only `SomePackage.dll` is included.

How can I tell my project to also include `SomePackage.runtimeconfig.json` in the bin folder?

**Note:** I'm using VS Code rather than Visual Studio

Comment: Did you work this out?